# What is the best way to filter the text using stringBuffer in java?

Tags: java

Here is the code I wrote for replacing the text. 
Input text is

> Apple, Computer

expected output is

> Apple

So I have written it like this:

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class One {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        one();
    }

    private static void one() {
        String fruit = "Apple";
        StringBuffer device = new StringBuffer("Computer");

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(fruit)) {
            if (device.length() == 0) {
                device.append(fruit);

                System.out.println("if:: " + device.append(fruit));

            }
            else {
                StringBuffer sss = device.insert(0, fruit + ", ");

                System.out.println(sss);
                // Apple,Computer
            }
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(device) && device.charAt(5) == ',') {
            StringBuffer output = device.delete(5, 14);
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
}
```

is any other way , please suggest

Comment: Please fix your code style. --- Please define "best". Are you looking for the "most readable" solution? The fastest solution? Solution with lowest memory overhead? Lowest amount of characters? Of linebreks? --- If the code works as intended, then it may be better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "`System.out.println("if:: "+device.append(fruit));`" will append `fruit` again. Is that what you intend?